# BLE: Interesting behavior

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am aware of MOTO G first version has bluetooth issues.

Background:

My app scans for beacons in the vicinity. The app works great on all Android phones except Motorola Moto G, 1st version with Android 5.1. On this phone, it finds all the beacons except one and the scanning is pretty fast as well. However, with this specific beacon (skybeacon), it only detects first packet and after that it takes forever to find this specific beacon while finding others. A simple conclusion is this specification beacon has issues, which might be true. However, it becomes more interesting from here.

To understand this more, I downloaded other BLE scanners from play store. When I used "BLE Analyzer" from bluevoid, it captures this beacon perfectly. I can see RSSI changing as I move the beacon and it is pretty fast. Once I push BLE Analyzer to background and check our app, surprisingly our app works now. I repeated this, 20/20 times my app captures this specific beacon as long as BLE Analyzer is pushed into background (by pressing home button). If I restart or uninstall or wont open BLE Analyzer at all, my app wont capture this specific beacon.

Possible explanations:

1. For good or bad this specific beacon is advertising in one channel and the default scanning on this specific phone is having a mismatch. If this is in the right direction, then how to change default scanning channels through app?
2. This phone might have an integrated chip for wifi, bluetooth and 3G, which might be true. When I disable wifi, I do not see any changes in behavior. When I disable data (3G, not 4G on this), it some times (2 out of 10) start capturing the skybeacon. Again 2 out of 10 times is not a repeatable solution.

Any thoughts?